# Kafka startup error with Ranger java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/security/auth/Authorizer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-ranger

I work with vanilla versions of components

- Apache Kafka 3.3.2  Scala 2.12
- Apache Ranger 2.3.0

**server.properties:** `authorizer.class.name=org.apache.ranger.authorization.kafka.authorizer.RangerKafkaAuthorizer`

The necessary libraries copied to **$KAFKA_HOME/libs**

- ranger-kafka-plugin-impl/
- ranger-kafka-plugin-shim-2.3.0.jar
- ranger-plugin-classloader-2.3.0.jar

When starting kafka, I get an error

```
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/security/auth/Authorizer
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:419)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:408)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at kafka.security.authorizer.AuthorizerUtils$.createAuthorizer(AuthorizerUtils.scala:31)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.createNewAuthorizer(KafkaConfig.scala:1689)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:386)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.security.auth.Authorizer
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
Jul 27 07:32:01 kafka01 kafka-server-start.sh[892961]:         ... 18 more
```

It looks like a library version conflict, maybe Ranger is compiled wrong

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

**UP:** Apparently there is a version conflict
I compiled the Ranger version from the wizard and there is not this error... It is a pity that the problem is not solved in the stable version of ranger 2.3 or 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is compiled wrong. See  https://github.com/apache/ranger/pull/133

This interface indeed does not exist in that version of Kafka, nor does that package

https://kafka.apache.org/33/javadoc/allpackages-index.html

You fix it by using a lower version of Kafka that does include it, or newer Ranger that uses correct interfaces. E.g. [Ranger 2.4.0 release only builds against Kafka 2.8.1](https://github.com/apache/ranger/blob/release-ranger-2.4.0/pom.xml#L162)